# What counts as different sources of income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business, income, expenses

I'm a freelance writer (in US), but I also do some freelance video editing, programming, and virtual assistance along the side. I'm wondering if each of this counts as a "separate source of income". In other words, do I need to submit different forms for each? Also, what about business expenses for each? For example, I had to hire a content editor for freelance writing, and I bought a video editing software for video editing.

Comment: Are you talking about specific tax forms? You don't fill out different personal tax returns for each source - you aggregate income and expenses for all activities in one return.

Comment: Are these separately incorporated businesses?  Or is it all just a sole proprietorship?  Do any of the individual businesses show a loss?

Comment: Where did you see the phrase “separate source of income”? If you help us understand why you are asking, we will be able to give you a more relevant answer.

Comment: @DStanley: yes and no. For US, if your businesses are sole prop (or disregarded LLC) they all go into one 1040 _return_, but you are supposed to use [separate _schedule C_ for 'each' business](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sc#idm140543711315104). OP: if these are all online computer-based, as it sounds like, IMO(!) you can reasonably call them parts of a single instance of 541990; but if e.g. you do freelance writing and also repair cars, or raise and sell horses, IRS wants those separated.